# URI to Web API action not working when application is published to IIS as a Web Application under Default Web Site

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, routes, asp.net-web-api2

I have added Web API 2 to an existing MVC 5 web application. I use methods of this Web API to return JSON data to MVC Views.

This is an example of an ajax call inside a view:

```
$.getJSON('@Url.RouteUrl("DefaultApi"
    , new { httproute = true, controller = "Data", action = "GetMyData" })'
    , function (data) {
        ... do sth with returned json data here ...
    });
```

this is the code being generated on the client:

```
$.getJSON("/api/Data/GetMyData", function (data) { ...
```

and this is how WebApiConfig.cs file looks like:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Everything works fine when I debug from visual studio. But when I deploy the app to IIS as an application under 'Default Web Site'  all links to Web API action methods are broken.

In other words `$.getJSON("/api/Data/GetMyData", function (data) { ...` works fine when I start a debugging session from Visual Studio but returns a 404 error when the app is deployed to IIS.

When I type

```
http://localhost/myAppVirtualPath/api/data/GetMyData
```

directly in the address line of the browser I get back results as expected.

It seems that the virtual path of the application needs to be added before '/api' in the URI. But `@Url.RouteUrl("DefaultApi"` fails to do so. Is there something obvious that I am missing here? I guess there is, but what could it be?

Comment: is `myAppVirtualPath` configured as an application in IIS ?

Comment: @CyrilDurand Yes, I have added it by right clicking on *Default Web Site*, then chose *Add Application...*

Comment: Did you test it with 'Url.Action("GetMyData","Data")' the same result?